# Indent <head> and <body> using HTML Tidy

Tags: html, macos, command-line, htmltidy

I want to **indent**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>List 1</li>
        <li>List 2</li>
        <li>List 3</li>
        <li>List 4</li>
        <li>List 5</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>List 1</li>
            <li>List 2</li>
            <li>List 3</li>
            <li>List 4</li>
            <li>List 5</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

with `tidy -config config.txt -m index.html`.

The `config.txt` looks like

```
doctype: html5
indent: auto
indent-spaces: 4
wrap: 0
tab-size: 4
quiet: yes
show-warnings: no
tidy-mark: no
```

The version is: `HTML Tidy for Apple macOS version 5.6.0`

I skimmed through [HTML Tidy 5.7.0 Options Quick Reference](http://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/quickref_next.html#indent-cdata) and tried a few things, but without success.

What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is your option `indent: auto`. In the [man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/tidy.1.html), you can read:

> ```
> If set to auto Tidy will decide whether or not to indent the content of tags such
> as <title>, <h1>-<h6>, <li>, <td>, or <p> based on the content including a block-
> level element.
> ```

When you set `indent` to `yes`, your `<head>` and `<body>` sections will be indented, but also all list items, which you might not like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
            Document
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>List 1
            </li>
            <li>List 2
            </li>
            <li>List 3
            </li>
            <li>List 4
            </li>
            <li>List 5
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

FYI: Instead of writing all options for `tidy` into a config file, you can also pass them as options by prefixing each option with `--` and adding the value separated by space. The minimal command to produce the above output is:

```sh
tidy --indent yes --indent-spaces 4 --quiet yes --tidy-mark no index.html
```

Might be usefull in some cases.